# Which name should be used for myhostname in Postfix's main.cf?

Tags: email, postfix, mail-transport-agent

For `#myhostname`, I should uncomment and put my hostname, i.e. the name I gave my VPS, right?
Or does it just go `myhostname = mydomain.net`, in other words don't edit the phrase 'myhostname' except to uncomment?

And for  `#myhostname = virtual.domian.tld`  is that to put a subdomain?

Should I add a listing for all including with and without `www`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `myhostname` should be set to the FQDN of your mail server. For example, if your server's hostname is "mail" and your domain is "example.com", your FQDN is "mail.example.com". The directive would look like this:

```
myhostname = mail.example.com
```

On a Linux system, you can get your FQDN using the hostname command:

```
hostname --fqdn
```

This should match the PTR record for the primary IP on the machine.

See the [Postfix documentation for myhostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname).

For accepting mail for subdomains which are not the server's hostname, you can use the [mydestination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) directive:

```
mydestination = mail.example.com, example.com, www.example.com
```

Comment: What would happen if myhostname is the same as mydomain?

Comment: @Braiam then you have failed to assign your server an actual hostname. Using what you assigned may still work however.

Comment: And what if you are not using this to receive mail and only using postfix to send email out from the server? Eg. I have a server hosting website mydomain.com but mail for mydomain.com is hosting a totally different place...